# Pandas - Pivot table while merging with two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table with two categorical columns and several numerical ones. I wish to pivot the table on a certain index (in the example the index is the client) while merging the two categorical columns into the names of the numerical ones. Is there a way to do this without a loop?

This is an example table :

| Client | Project | Case | Spending | value_mean | value_std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MisterA | Project_15 | 4 | 100122 | 9655.566667 | 12.70499327 |
| MisterA | Project_15 | 2 | 4015 | 9653 | 17.66352173 |
| MisterA | Project_15 | 7 | 8953 | 94.4 | 2.065591118 |
| MisterA | Project_16 | 1 | 3922 | 65519.4 | 0.894427191 |
| MisterA | Project_16 | 6 | 8953 | 21093.5 | 17816.03006 |
| MisterA | Project_16 | 7 | 8953 | 30665.3 | 30643.27374 |
| MisterA | Project_16 | 2 | 4015 | 65517.8 | 1.788854382 |
| MisterA | Project_16 | 4 | 100122 | 65518.86667 | 1.153402392 |
| MisterA | Project_16 | 5 | 3109 | 65519 | 1.632993162 |
| MisterA | Project_18 | 4 | 100122 | 78.84444444 | 16.89884719 |
| MisterA | Project_18 | 5 | 3109 | 5820 | 6735.594059 |
| MisterB | Project_15 | 7 | 9063 | 94.6 | 1.646545205 |
| MisterB | Project_15 | 2 | 4015 | 9636 | 14.38749457 |
| MisterB | Project_15 | 6 | 8968 | 93.6 | 1.264911064 |
| MisterB | Project_16 | 5 | 4016 | 65519 | 1.414213562 |
| MisterB | Project_16 | 6 | 8968 | 22375.3 | 16701.95844 |
| MisterB | Project_16 | 7 | 9063 | 36482.5 | 31091.74401 |
| MisterB | Project_16 | 4 | 98966 | 65518.78 | 1.133333333 |
| MisterB | Project_18 | 1 | 2906 | 79.5 | 1.914854216 |
| MisterB | Project_18 | 5 | 4016 | 6257 | 6399.977109 |
| MisterB | Project_18 | 6 | 8968 | 13304.3 | 52.38330947 |
| MisterB | Project_18 | 2 | 4015 | 78.8 | 1.095445115 |

I want it something like this:

| Client | Project_15_Case_4_Spending | Project_15_Case_4_value_mean | Project_15_Case_4_value_std | Project_15_Case_2_Spending | Project_15_Case_2_value_mean | Project_15_Case_2_value_std | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MisterA | 100122 | 9655.566667 | 12.70499327 | 4015 | 9653 | 17.66352173 | ... |
| MisterB | 9063 | 94.6 | 1.646545205 | 4015 | 9636 | 14.38749457 | ... |

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way -> use `pivot_table` and then rename the `columns`. You can use `fill_Value=0` if required.

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Client', columns=['Project', 'Case'], values=[
                     'Spending', 'value_mean', 'value_std'])
df1.columns = [f'{j}_Case_{k}_{i}' for i, j, k in df1.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):  you can then keep the column sequence following original row by row 3 columns sequence, as shown in the column sequence in expected output:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['Client', 'Project', 'Case']).stack().unstack([1,2]).unstack()
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}_{x[2]}')
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)


    Client  Project_15_4_Spending  Project_15_4_value_mean  Project_15_4_value_std  Project_15_2_Spending  Project_15_2_value_mean  Project_15_2_value_std  Project_15_7_Spending  Project_15_7_value_mean  Project_15_7_value_std  Project_16_1_Spending  Project_16_1_value_mean  Project_16_1_value_std  Project_16_6_Spending  Project_16_6_value_mean  Project_16_6_value_std  Project_16_7_Spending  Project_16_7_value_mean  Project_16_7_value_std  Project_16_2_Spending  Project_16_2_value_mean  Project_16_2_value_std  Project_16_4_Spending  Project_16_4_value_mean  Project_16_4_value_std  Project_16_5_Spending  Project_16_5_value_mean  Project_16_5_value_std  Project_18_4_Spending  Project_18_4_value_mean  Project_18_4_value_std  Project_18_5_Spending  Project_18_5_value_mean  Project_18_5_value_std  Project_15_6_Spending  Project_15_6_value_mean  Project_15_6_value_std  Project_18_1_Spending  Project_18_1_value_mean  Project_18_1_value_std  Project_18_6_Spending  Project_18_6_value_mean  Project_18_6_value_std  Project_18_2_Spending  Project_18_2_value_mean  Project_18_2_value_std
0  MisterA               100122.0              9655.566667               12.704993                 4015.0                   9653.0               17.663522                 8953.0                     94.4                2.065591                 3922.0                  65519.4                0.894427                 8953.0                  21093.5             17816.03006                 8953.0                  30665.3             30643.27374                 4015.0                  65517.8                1.788854               100122.0              65518.86667                1.153402                 3109.0                  65519.0                1.632993               100122.0                78.844444               16.898847                 3109.0                   5820.0             6735.594059                    NaN                      NaN                     NaN                    NaN                      NaN                     NaN                    NaN                      NaN                     NaN                    NaN                      NaN                     NaN
1  MisterB                    NaN                      NaN                     NaN                 4015.0                   9636.0               14.387495                 9063.0                     94.6                1.646545                    NaN                      NaN                     NaN                 8968.0                  22375.3             16701.95844                 9063.0                  36482.5             31091.74401                    NaN                      NaN                     NaN                98966.0              65518.78000                1.133333                 4016.0                  65519.0                1.414214                    NaN                      NaN                     NaN                 4016.0                   6257.0             6399.977109                 8968.0                     93.6                1.264911                 2906.0                     79.5                1.914854                 8968.0                  13304.3               52.383309                 4015.0                     78.8                1.095445
```